# Twitter bot: Tweets are lost during the rate limit period

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

The below code is Twitter bot stream API triggered on several rules. Everything is working fine except when the rate limit is hit. The tweets tagged during the rate limit waiting period are lost. How can I recover those tweets? Are there better ways to handle the rate limit? I tried increasing the sleep period. That didn't help.

```
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
  def on_connect(self):
    print("connected")


  def on_data(self, data):
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    token = jwt.encode(json_data, hmac_secret,algorithm='HS256')
    header_payload = {'payload': token}
    requests.post(app_url, headers=header_payload)
    print("data--> ",data)
    time.sleep(0.19)


stream = MyStream(bearer_token=os.environ['TWITTER_DEV_TOKEN'],wait_on_rate_limit=True)

stream.filter(tweet_fields="in_reply_to_user_id,author_id,created_at,conversation_id",
              expansions="author_id,entities.mentions.username",
              user_fields="profile_image_url,created_at,verified")
```